# Scala macro annotation typecheck for implicit class fails

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros

Macro sample code:

```
package macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox.Context
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation
class Ant extends StaticAnnotation {
    def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Unit = macro Ant.impl
}
object Ant {
    def impl(c: Context)(annottees: c.Tree*): c.Tree = {
        import c.universe._
        c.internal.enclosingOwner.asType.toType // this line is Ok
        // ! Any commented line below causes the same compilation error
        // c.internal.enclosingOwner.asType.toType.decls
        // c.mirror.staticClass(c.internal.enclosingOwner.fullName + ".A".toString)
        // c.typecheck(annottees.head)
        q"""implicit class A(val v: Int) extends AnyVal { def ask() = println("ok") }"""
    }
}
```

*Changing whitebox.Context to macros.Context or blackbox.Context does not help.*
*Changing arguments withImplicitViewsDisabled=true, or withMacrosDisabled=true has no effect.*

Exec sample code:

```
package test
import macros.Ant
object Test extends App {
    val a = new A(42)
    a.ask() // Output should be "ok" (not 42)
    // ! removing [implicit] lets code be compiled
    @Ant implicit class A(v: Int) { def ask() = println(v)}
}
```

So, removing line ***c.typecheck(annottees.head)*** and / or word ***implicit*** in line ***@Ant implicit class A(v: Int)*** lets code be compiled.
Otherwise compilation crashes with error:

```
Error:scalac:
no progress in completing object Test: <?>
while compiling: D:\Projects\_Schemee\TestMacro1\src\test\Test.scala
during phase: globalPhase=typer, enteringPhase=namer
library version: version 2.11.6
compiler version: version 2.11.6
reconstructed args: -nobootcp -classpath ...
last tree to typer: Ident(v)
tree position: <unknown>
tree tpe: Int
symbol: value v
symbol definition: v: Int (a TermSymbol)
symbol package: test
symbol owners: value v -> method A -> object Test
call site: method A in object Test in package test
<Cannot read source file>
```

*Compiled under latest IntelliJ. With and without Sbt.*

The question is: how to use typecheck in macro annotation with implicit classes? (or am i missing something?)

EDITED:

Besides that that error is caused when trying to access enclosingOwner declarations or mirror class A "manually".

[Github link](https://github.com/just-4-fun/MacroAnt)

[Issue link](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9224)

Comment: FWIW, WFM. (Doesn't crash.) How are you compiling? Try clean build, of course.

Comment: @som-snytt Project is compiled under latest IntelliJ. I tried SBT project with paradise plugin added in build.sbt, as so as IDE-based Scala project with manually added paradise compiler plugin. Tried Scala 2.11.5 and 2.11.6.  Still no luck. I slightly modified sources so that running app should print "ok". What is your compiling environment?

Comment: Vanilla latest scalac. I didn't experiment. It's not obvious to me that typechecking a tree with an annotation that invokes me circularly ought to work, but I wouldn't speculate without reproducing the failure.

Comment: @som-snytt Tested as SBT project as well. Still no luck. Seems problem is not IDE dependent. Created  an issue https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9224.

Comment: I'm currently at ScalaDays, so I probably won't have time to take a look this week. How urgent is this for you?

Comment: @Eugene Burmako  The lib i currently develop depends on the ability to typecheck macro annotee in implicit class. It's not urgent. The question is in principle possibility to do it with macros so to decide to dig deeper or look for other ways. Honestly i'm not quite sure that the problem is in macros and not in my understanding of them. So enjoy the Event :)

Comment: @Eugene Burmako   Discovered some other cases when same error is thrown (see edited). Tried different options of compilation: no progress. Seems it's not a compilation environment related problem. Need help.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like an sbt bug or interaction with compiler behavior.

The original exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at xsbt.Dependency$ExtractDependenciesByMemberRefTraverser$$anonfun$1.isDefinedAt(Dependency.scala:142)
```

That location:

```
      val typeSymbolCollector = new CollectTypeTraverser({
        case tpe if !tpe.typeSymbol.isPackage => tpe.typeSymbol
      })
```

The traverser has a comment suggesting similar issues:

```
/*
 * Some macros appear to contain themselves as original tree.
 * We must check that we don't inspect the same tree over and over.
 * See https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8486
 *     https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1237
 *     https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1544
 */
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Seems roots are deeper than my hands can plunge.